# Intercalate 2 arrays with the same length

Tags: python, arrays, tuples

Let's say the entrance in the first line asks the length of both arrays(one integer), so the 2n lines requests the **elements** of those 2 arrays. The output should print 2n lines, with both arrays intercalated.

```
Entrance                          Output
    3 #length of both arrays        2 #array1[0]
    2 #array1                       4 #array2[0]   
    5                               5    ...
    9 #array1 finished              4
    4 #array2                       9
    4                               8
    8
```

I was trying to create the code, but I really don't know how to proceed:

```
n = len(array)
2*n = len(arrays)
arrays = []
q = 2*n
array1 =  

while True:
   x = int(input())
   arrays.append(x)
   if len(arrays) > q:
```

When the problem says '*N lines*' I just think about while repetition.

Answer (score 1):

this seems like a coding challenge - but I bite.

Can you not simply do

```
l = [[a, b] for (a, b) in zip(array1, array2)]
reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, l)
```

or less terse

```
 output = []
 for (a, b) in zip(array1, array2):
     output.append(a)
     output.append(b)
```

The main fact is we can use `zip` to iterate through these lists together.